# HTML characters are not transalated during render

Tags: html, css, vue.js, prose-mirror

I have some js code which renders the following HTML

```html
<div contenteditable="false" tabindex="0" class="ProseMirror">
    <p> didn&#039;t project a significant increase</p>
</div>
```

In the browser, it actually displays the characters `#039;` instead of converting it to `'` is there a way to force/prevent the browser from doing this conversion?

Comment: Can you include the JS code in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering an [HTML entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity), it may need to be compiled.  You can use one of these options:

- ## Interpolation

```html
<p> didn{{ `&#039;` }}t project a significant increase</p>
```

- ## `v-html`

```html
<p> didn<span v-html="`&#039;`"></span>t project a significant increase</p>
```

Note that these first two examples are using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), not single quotes.

- ## Render function

If using a render function, you can set the `innerHTML` `domProps`:

```js
render(h) {
  return h('span', {
    domProps: {
      innerHTML: 'didn&#039;t project a significant increase'
    }
  });
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/5xyzonbc)

---

**Original**

You're missing an `&`, it should be:

```
<p> didn&#039;t project a significant increase</p>
```

Comment: I  made the mistake with `&` while typing the question. I've edited it. Even with &, I still get the code version being ddisplayed

Comment: Hey Dan, the answer didn't solve my specific problem mostly because of my very specific situation. I couldn't use interpolation because I didn't know which exact part to the string will have the HTML code. I couldn't also use the `v-html` like solutions because the items were rendered using https://github.com/ProseMirror/prosemirror. Butt I believe you're solution will work for most people so I'l accept it. Thannks for putting the time into this.

Comment: Ah, ok, you're welcome.  Let me know if you want to further describe what you mean, maybe there's a way to extract the HTML part.

Answer (score 0):

In my specific situation. I ended. up solving the problem by using the `he` HTML encoder/deccoder https://www.npmjs.com/package/he to decode the HTML before rendering.